# Infinite values variable

Tags: lua

I'm trying to have a variable with infinite values, if you compare it to 0 I want it to be 0 and the same with any other number/string.

```
if ( epicvar == "random string" ) then
```

Comment: So, you want something that, when compared with anything, always returns 0?

Comment: This is impossible, at least in native Lua. What's the real problem you are trying to solve？Because it looks like a [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I would suggest `__eq` but it only fires if both types have the same metatable. On the bright side you can always replace your comparison with `true` since you know the answer before hand!

Comment: @NoName I want something that returns true no matter what the comparison is, like (magic == "asd") = true

Comment: @YuHao I'm trying to find a way to bypass a simple security system (we're debating in a forum about that and I'd like to know if it's possible to bypass)

_currentIP = server.getIP()
if ( tostring(serverIP) == "192.168.1.1" ) then blockCode end_

I want to re-write the variable 'serverIP' with something that will always return true in a comparison like < math.huge for numbers.

 edit: it's all encrypted so I need to edit it the variable using another file in the same project.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. I don't know of any language which offers that behavior.

A single variable can only store a finite amount of information. You can store multiple values in a variable, but desiring "infinite values" suggests to me that you should do some reading and familiarize yourself with fundamental programming concepts.

There is a constant `math.huge` which is used to represent the *value* of +infinity. However, it is a discrete value.

And just for fun, a hacky way to emulate this behavior might be to create an instance of a Lua class containing a function that always returns true. Again, this is just for fun. You cannot define variables with infinite values.

```
local Magic = {}
Magic.__index = Magic

-- (i'd also suggest a toggable "epicvar" flag to enable/disable the property)
function Magic.new()
    return setmetatable({}, Magic)
end

function Magic.compare(self, randomVar)
    return true
end

local m = Magic.new()

-- m:compare(...) always returns true no matter what you give it
if m:compare("random string") then
    print('success')
end
```

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to bypass a simple security system (we're debating in a forum about that and I'd like to know if it's possible to bypass) currentIP = server.getIP() if ( tostring(serverIP) == "192.168.1.1" ) then blockCode end I want to re-write the variable 'serverIP' with something that will always return true in a comparison like < math.huge for numbers, it uses 'if' in the source so I can't use your way. edit: it's all encrypted so I need to edit it the variable using another file in the same project.

Comment: If you can modify the value *any* one of those variables (`server`, `currentIP`, or `serverIP`), you can bypass the check. However, you can't modify variables in separate source files unless you (1) edit the original code, or (2) edit an external function or variable that is referenced by the original code. Look for where those variables are defined. If you can modify `server`, you would be able to do: `server = {getIP = function () return true; end }`.